# How to set a blazor component to single render?

Tags: c#, blazor

In blazor, when I run the StateHasChanged() method, it re-renders the page and re-sets any of the properties being sent to my child components.

Some of my child components are just JavaScript wrappers, so I don't need the child component to re-render.

Anyone know what the syntax is to disable multiple renders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [ShouldRender()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#suppress-ui-refreshing). If I remember right it will be always be (pre)rendered once.

```
protected override bool ShouldRender()
{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!